# Bootstrap-select - Don't show selected value

Tags: icons, bootstrap-select

I'm using bootstrap-select to create my selectpicker.

I set an icon for the select using :

```
data-style="glyphicon glyphicon-list"
```

When I'm selecting an option, the option selected is place near the icon but I don't want that.
I don't want to see the selected option, only the icon.

Two printscreen to illustrate :

Before =>
http://hpics.li/07182fd

After =>
http://hpics.li/c1dd1ca

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I found a way !

My code :

```
$('select.selectpicker').on('change', function(){
    $(".glyphicon-list .filter-option.pull-left").empty();
});
```

glyphicon-list is the class of the button.btn.dropdown-toggle.selectpicker.